# Entity Framework6 Transaction vs Transaction handled in Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, optimization, transactions

I have a stored procedure that executes a transaction, the code was written long time ago and the SP looks something like this:

```
begin transaction
    begin try
        ...
        commit transaction
    end try
    begin catch
        ...
        rollback transaction
    end catch
```

Now. I know that EF6 allows you to use transactions smarter:

```
using (var db = myDbContext)
    using (var dbTransaction = db.DataBase.BeginTransaction)
    {
        try
        {
            //do stuff...
            dbTransaction.Commit();
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            dbTransaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
```

I prefer the EF approach, but I would like to know if from the performance perspective is better to use an EF for Transactions or SP that encapsulate a Transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Using T-SQL implies that you are executing other statements as well. This means that you can save server roundtrips. `BeginTransaction` executes a round-trip.

If you don't have other T-SQL to run then both versions with execute the same number of roundtrips.

Roundtrips are the dominating cost. Transaction management is extremely cheap.

This is a known anti-pattern:

```
    catch(Exception)
    {
        dbTransaction.Rollback();
    }
```

Just do nothing. The transaction will rollback on `Dispose`. This is redundant and swallows the exception which is a really bad outcome.

Also note, that you don't have to use procs to execute T-SQL.

Unless you think that these 2 additional roundtrips are a performance problem you should go with the much simpler and more reliable C# transaction management. T-SQL is *horrible* at error handling.

Comment: That was what I wanted to ask. I've seen an example with .Rollback(), but the commit actually writes the data so unless you say `Commit()`, won't it rollback no matter what happened? And on catch you should treat the exception, right?

Comment: Actually, I simply need a performance improvement and I was wondering whether to continue using the SP version or switch to EF transaction. Would it create additional traffic or any issue if you use EF/SP? This is my main concern, if EF transaction (**without .Rollback()**) is a performance improvement above the SP transaction handling.

Comment: It would be a useless default to commit by default. The default is to rollback. The usual exception handling principles apply: Handle the exception where you can meaningful do something about it. Normally, you can't do anything and must fail the incoming request. So probably you don't need a catch at all.

Comment: EF transaction handling is actually identical to ADO.NET handling (EF just delegates). ADO.NET handling never has any perf improvement over a custom batch that incorporates both the tran as well as the actual statements to be executed. If you want further analysis it would be helpful to compare two pieces of code. Feel free to edit them into the question. Make sure that the code does not only transactions but also some dummy statement such as `SELECT NULL`. @Minsk

Comment: did some tests on arround 200k records and EF acted slower than the SP... Did some selects and updates.

Comment: It's important to understand the reason why. Can't say without seeing the code.

Answer (score -1):

From the performance point of view it is better to use stored procedure with transaction because it can be much more optimized by SQL Server. From the end user point of view it doesn't matter unless you operate on very big tables. From the developer point of view is much simpler to use EF and that really matters.